# Is this ES6 refactor accurate?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

When I look at this code:

```
CustomUIHandler.prototype.createFormSession = function(formId, payload) {
  function FormSession(formId, payload, common) {
    this.formId = formId;
    this.payload = payload;
    this.common = common;
  }

  FormSession.prototype.getContainer = function(clientContext) {
    return xmui.XmuiHandler.getContainer(clientContext);
  }

  FormSession.prototype.startSession = function(clientContext, actionContext) {
    this.actionContext = actionContext;
    this.clientContext = clientContext;
  }

  FormSession.prototype.promiseFormInput = function() {
    return this.renderForm();
  }

  FormSession.prototype.renderForm = function() {
    var _this = this;
    var uiContainer = this.getContainer(this.clientContext);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      uiContainer.append($(
        "<div>\
            <input id='myText' type='text'>\ <
        button id = 'continueButton' > Continue < /button>\ <
        /div>"
      });

      $('#continueButton').click(function() {
        uiContainer.empty();
        var formInput = com.ts.mobile.sdk.FormInput.createFormInputSubmissionRequest({
          data: document.getElementById("myText").value
        });
        resolve(formInput);
      });
    })
  }
  FormSession.prototype.onContinue = function(payload) {

  }

  FormSession.prototype.onError = function(payload) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(payload));
  }

  FormSession.prototype.endSession = function() {

  }

  return new FormSession(formId, payload, this.common);

}
```

The above is the original full file of code.

Am I correct in refactoring this as:

```
class FormSession extends CustomUIHandler {
  constructor(formId, payload, common) {
    super();
    this.formId = formId;
    this.payload = payload;
    this.common = common;
  }
}

createFormSession(formId, payload) {

}
```

Comment: In first example, `FormSession` does not extend `CustomUIHandler`. There is probably code missing here, but all that is going on there is that a method (`createFormSession`) presumably creates an instance of `FormSession`.

Comment: The first piece of code makes no sense. `createFormSession` is defined as a function that does nothing: it defines a function in its local scope, but never uses it, and so that inner function object is garbage collected.

Comment: @FelixKling, I guess then I do not understand what that `createFormSession` presumably creating an instance of `FormSession` in ES6 looks like. I added some more code in OP.

Comment: The original code makes no sense as @trincot says. Did you leave something out?

Comment: @Barmar, the first code snippet is actually lines 1 through 11 of the file I am looking at. Maybe that's why I am stumped as to how this would look like in ES6. When you say it does not make sense, can you elaborate? By the way I have added more of the original code.

Comment: It defines a local function. But it never calls or returns the local function. Since it's a local function, nothing outside this scope can call it. So it's defining a function that can never be used, unless there's code you left out that uses it.

Comment: Without seeing how these functions fit together in the larger process, it's hard to tell how it should be refactored in ES6.

Comment: The original code should probably end with something like `return new FormSession(formId, payload, <something that fills in common>)`

Comment: But defining new prototype functions for every `FormSession` you create seems strange.

Comment: @Barmar, I have added the whole file and yes it does end with `return new FormSession()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218055/discussion-between-daniel-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 class syntax doesn't provide a way to add new methods to an existing class. For that, you still have to use assignment to `classname.prototype.methodname`.

But you can use ES6 syntax to define the internal `FormSession` class.

But it's not really a good idea to define the whole `FormSession` class every time you create a `FormSession`. It should be defined just once, and used within the `createFormSession` method. If you don't want it to get into the global scope, you can define it in an IIFE.

```js
(function() {
  class FormSession {
    constructor(formId, payload, common) {
      this.formId = formId;
      this.payload = payload;
      this.common = common;
    }

    getContainer(clientContext) {
      return xmui.XmuiHandler.getContainer(clientContext);
    }

    startSession(clientContext, actionContext) {
      this.actionContext = actionContext;
      this.clientContext = clientContext;
    }

    promiseFormInput() {
      return this.renderForm();
    }

    renderForm() {
      var _this = this;
      var uiContainer = this.getContainer(this.clientContext);
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        uiContainer.append($(
          "<div>\
            <input id='myText' type='text'>\ <
          button id = 'continueButton' > Continue < /button>\ < /
          div > "
        });

        $('#continueButton').click(function() {
          uiContainer.empty();
          var formInput = com.ts.mobile.sdk.FormInput.createFormInputSubmissionRequest({
            data: document.getElementById("myText").value
          });
          resolve(formInput);
        });
      })
    }
    onContinue(payload) {

    }

    onError(payload) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(payload));
    }

    endSession() {

    }
  }

  CustomUIHandler.prototype.createFormSession = function(formId, payload) {
    return new FormSession(formId, payload, this.common);
  }
})();
```